# Build a custom vim binary with python support

Tags: python, linux, vim

### Background

The Debian 11 `vim` package doesn't include `python3` support.  See the section titled "*No python support in Debian 11 vim - evidence*" below

I need `vim` with `python3` support for the [YouCompleteMe vim plugin](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe).   To build a new `vim`, I downloaded the vim 9.0 tarball into `/opt/` on my Debian 11 system and extracted it... explicitly:

```bash
$ cd /opt
$ sudo wget http://ftp.vim.org/pub/pub/vim/unix/vim-9.0.tar.bz2
$ sudo bunzip2 ./vim-9.0.tar.bz2
$ sudo chown -R mpenning:mpenning vim/
```

I built it with...

```bash
$ cd /opt/vim
$ ./configure \
 --enable-python3interp=yes \
 --with-python3-command=python3.9 \
 --with-features=huge \
 --with-compiledby="mike@pennington.net"
$ make
$ sudo cp src/vim /usr/bin/vim
```

However, now I see these errors when I start `vim`...

```bash
$ vim foo.py
2022-10-24 09:08:31 [INFO] Editing 'foo.py'.
failed to load colors/lists/default.vim
failed to load colors/lists/default.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

### Question

How can I build a Debian `vim` binary with `python3`?

### No python support in Debian 11 vim - evidence

```bash
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)
Included patches: 1-2434
Extra patches: 8.2.3402, 8.2.3403, 8.2.3409, 8.2.3428
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              -perl              +title
-clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
-clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -X11
-dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wdate-time -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim-DtwDbo/vim-8.2.2434=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
$
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need vim with python syntax highlighting

Python syntax highlighting is built-in so you don't need to build Vim manually to get it. You are wasting your and everyone's time.

"Python support" is unrelated to syntax highlighting. It refers to the Python scripting interface that allow users to (partially) write Vim plugins in Python. Having `-python` or `-python3` in `:version` has zero incidence on Vim's ability to highlight Python.

FWIW, you don't have to build a new vim binary if you install the `vim-nox` Debian package instead of depending on the `vim` Debian package.  `vim-nox` embeds several scripting languages in the `vim.nox` binary build.

Comment: I modified the question... `python3` support is required for the plugins in my `~/.vimrc` even if `+python3` is not required for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Still, the `vim-gtk3`, `vim-gtk`, and `vim-nox` packages give you Python support so the exercice is pointless. There's even a `vim-youcompleteme` package that, presumably, should pull all the dependencies.

Comment: Regarding `vim-youcompleteme`, I do all my work in python virtualenv.  Global availability of `YouCompleteMe()` in my `python` interpreter would only complicate matters more